# Екземпліфікант на позначення неуточненої особи

Tags: переклад, from-english, власні-назви, legal-terms

В англійській мові у разі виникнення потреби назвати якусь особу, ім'я якої не можна встановити використовують замінник (екземпліфікант) [John Doe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe) (чол.) або Jane Doe (жін.).

Чи є наразі такий екземпліфікант в українській? [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) наводить лише варіант [ім'ярек](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA), але поза його початковим церковним контекстом він мені не зустрічався.

Comment: Пов'язане питання: **[Батькович](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/661/4)**.

Comment: Використання складових, що походять від одного імені, на мою, думку привертає увагу читача та спонукає його до обережного аналізу "а чи справді таке можливо"? Наприклад: Петренко Петро Петрович.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Усталеного позначення, наскільки мені відомо, немає.

Різноманітні установи і ЗМІ використовують різні замінники:

- [image: Петренко Володимир Іванович] [Петренко Володимир Іванович](http://www.rivne1.tv/Info/?id=47340)
- [image: Іванов Іван Іванович] [Іванов Іван Іванович](http://tpu.org.ua/zapolnenie-zayavleniya-o-perexode-na-edinyj-nalog-2012/)
- [image: Іванов Іван Іванович] ще один [Іванов Іван Іванович](https://nakaz.com.ua/ua/zmina-vidiv-dijalnosti-kved-kiyv)
- [image: Петров Сергій Іванович] [Петров Сергій Іванович](https://www.slideshare.net/ssuser74c849/11-2012)
- [image: Іванов Петро Сергійович] [Іванов Петро Сергійович](http://zvenygorodska.rda.org.ua/informacijni-kartki-blanki-zayav-zrazki-zapovnennya-zayav-subektiv-nadannya-administrativnih-poslug-16-39-36-11-07-2016/)

Тощо

Comment: які негарні приклади подають українські ЗМІ.

Answer (score 7):

Не знаю щодо широкого вжитку, але `ім’ярек` використовували:

> *Поїзд генерала (ім'ярек)* — Микола Хвильовий в новелі "Кіт у чоботях"
>
> *...промовляв голова комнезаму (ім'ярек) Херсонської губернії...* — Остап Вишня у збірці "Літературно-мистецькі усмішки"
>
> *«Я, ім’ярек, ознайомився з ділом і вважаю слідство закінчене. Більше нічого не маю додати».* —Іван Багряний у романі "Сад Гетсиманський"
>
> От тільки жаль, ніякий же дослідник
> вже не встановить, хто він, ім’ярек.
> — Ліна Костенко у поемі-балладі "Скіфська Одіссея"

Інформація зі сторінки [mova.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

В шаблонах офіційних документів зустрічаються:

- Іванов Іван Іванович
- Петров Петро Петрович
- Сидоров Сидор Сидорович

В жартівливому контексті вживаються такі загальні імена:

- Вася/Василь Пупкін (`Зробив це якийсь Вася Пупкін`);
- Пушкін (`Ну і хто за тебе уроки вчитиме - Пушкін?`);
- Папа Римський (`Ну і хто за це буде робити - Папа Римський?`).

Comment: Вася Пупкін, то в Росії.

Comment: Власне, Іванов/Петров/Сидоров — це теж російські реалії, хоча в нас їх теж часто застосовують в ролі екземпліфікантів, іноді адаптуючи до Петренків/Сидорчуків.