# Використання Батькович замість по батькові

Tags: власні-назви

Ніде не знайшов коли можна використовувати Батькович/Батьківна для заміни по батькові.

У російських джерелах написано що це "жартівливе звернення до чоловіків або юнаків".

Чи це справедливо і для української мови (що це саме жартівливе звернення)? Чи можна використовувати "Батькович" коли у контексті очікується патронім, але по батькові невідоме (при зверненні до людини, при розповіді про третю людину, у літературі)?

*(Літературний приклад - коли богатир, якого називають по імені і по батькові збирається битися із змієм, то змія називають Змій Змієвич)*

Чи є інші "замінники", які можна використовувати коли по батькові не відоме?

Comment: `Батькович`, здається, жартівливе. Ввічливо було б додати `пан` або `добродій`, які вживаються і без патронімів.

Comment: Чому *Змієвич*? Ви десь зустрічали? Я думала, що за аналогією з *Андрій - Андрійович*, *Сергій - Сергійович* має бути *Змійович*.

Comment: Погугліть. Ось знайшов [Історію української літератури](http://litopys.org.ua/hrushukr/hrush410.htm) Грушевського: "З другого боку, ідея поганства свійського, староруського (билинне Ідолище і Зміяка-Перун різних переказів) асоціювалася з ідеєю поганства степового, печенізько-половецько-татарського. Тугарин-Тугорхан зветься **Змієвичем**; Кожем’яка — переможець печенізького богатиря стає змієборцем, який змушує змія викопати глибокі рови і насипати ті високі «змієві» вали, які боронять, Русь від степової сили, і п."

Comment: @Artemix, не ображайтеся. Я просто здивована, що не за правилами, тому й запитала. Чесно кажучи, й досі не розумію, чому *Змієвич*. Може, тому, що це замінник не по батькові, а на кшталт прізвиська (прізвища)? Окрім цього, зустрічається й *Тугарин Змійович* -  [тут 1](https://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/1011472/50/Ukrainski_bilini_%28zbirka%29.html), [тут 2](http://slovoor.runvira.in.ua/SO13/St13VerC.htm) . От і думай, як правильно :)

Comment: Я не ображаюсь, просто більш нічого іншого не можу запропонувати :) Можу лише додати що Змійовичів (179) в гуглі знайшлося трохи менше за Змієвичей (211), можливо такий перекіс через цитати з Грушевського. Думаю що через "є" передається літописне написання, сучасні збірки казок змінюють його на "йо".

Comment: В російській мові це взагалі ознака деякої фамільярності, як на мене. Іншим прикладом є звернення до знайомого по-батькові (Петрович, Сергіїч). Незнайома, або малознайома людина може й образитись. Корректніше буде пан/пані, шановний/шановна або добродій.

Answer (score 4):

Надибала дуже цікаву статтю Галини Лукаш [«Онімна гра в сучасній номінації»](http://www.linguisticstudies.org/home/linguistics-studies/volume-30/ethnolinguistics-linguoculturology-and-onomastics-state-and-perspectives-of-research/onymic-play-in-modern-nomination), в якій пані професорка проаналізувала "основні механізми створення нових ***`квазіонімних номінацій`*** усного мовлення, **які за своїм лексичним змістом та словотвірною онімною моделлю нагадують власні назви і можуть бути їм омонімічними**".

Зокрема, мовознавець відзначає:

> Під терміном «***`квазіоніми`***» (від лат. quasi − ‘ніби, начебто’;
>   онім − ‘власна назва’) розуміють **загальні назви, омонімічні власним
>   назвам** [Андреев 2005: 5]. Квазіоніми утворюються на базі різних
>   лексичних одиниць і становлять собою загальні назви, які на основі
>   онімних моделей і за допомогою онімних формантів набули вигляду
>   власних назв, але разом з тим їхнє апелятивне значення залишилося
>   прозорим для мовців [Там само]. В.М.  Андреєв як приклад наводить
>   арготичні рос. квазіоніми *Мешок Петрович* − ‘*пляшка горілки*’;
>   *козлостан* − ‘*табірна система*’.
>
> **Процес утворення подібних лексем названо словотвором за аналогією, або словотвором за моделлю власної назви.** Українська мова дає безліч
>   таких прикладів-мовленнєвих квазіонімів: *Сахар Медович* − ‘нещира,
>   лукава, улеслива людина’, *Глек Макітрович* − ‘йолоп’ (сема −
>   ‘порожній посуд’); *Кобра Іванівна*, *Кобра Львівна*, *Тигра Львівна,
>   Пантера Львівна, Змія **`Батьківна`** (Іванівна)* − ‘зла, лайлива жінка’;
>   *Глухар Тетерович* ‒’глухий’; *Мороз Іванович* ‒ ‘дурний’ (сема ‒ сленгове молодіжне мороз, тобто ‘байдужа до всього людина’; пор.
>   відморозитись, тобто ‘виявити повну байдужість’); *Розтапша Іванівна*
>   −‘незібрана людина’, *Лапша Іванівна* ‒ ‘людина, яку легко обдурити’;
>   *Кульома Іванівна* ‒ ‘забудько’; *Мегера Іванівна* ‒ ‘зла людина’, *Балда Іванівна* ‒ ‘дурна людина’; *Іван Бражник, Неминайкорчма, Непролийкрапля* − ‘любителі випити’ [ФСССГД 2013]. У молодіжному
>   сленгу вживається квазіонім *стьобич* − ‘жартівник, веселун’ (від
>   стібатися − ‘насміхатися, іронізувати’) [ССУС 2006].
>
> У наведених прикладах широко вживаний **конотонім** *`Іванович (Іванівна)`*, рівнозначний **квазіотецтву** ***`Батькович`***. Такий
>   умовний, «ключовий», замінник імені по батькові у поєднанні з повним
>   іменем у конотонімних сполученнях мав би сприяти вияву шанування у
>   звертанні до особи. Але місце особових імен в антропонімній формулі
>   посідають апелятиви-характеристики *Кобра, Тигра, Змія, Розтапша,
>   Лапша, Кульома, Мегера, Балда, Мороз*, граматично подібні до імен, і
>   номінація відзначається каламбурним використанням загальної назви
>   замість схожої за формою ВН. У результаті збережено зв’язок із
>   первісною негативною семантикою апелятива, на яку накладається онімне
>   референтне співзначення. На нашу думку, спосіб творення цих
>   квазіонімних сполучень ‒ онімна паронімія, коли особливу роль відіграє
>   апелятивна семантика їх формативів.

У статті автор ще пояснює творення й уживання **квазіантропонімів** (*Чайковський* (варіант: *ЧайКофський*) – назва кав’ярень; *Носовський* – назви крамниць з продажу панчох та шкарпеток, *Путлер*: Пут(ін)+(Гіт)лер) та **квазітопонімів** (*Донбабве* і *Луганда*) та інших.

Резюмує пані Лукаш так:

> Отже, поява квазіонімів, у процес творення яких залучаються різні
>   інтернаціональні та національні культурні ресурси, пов’язані з онімною
>   лексикою, є традиційним ігровим вплітанням нових лексичних одиниць у
>   процес номінації дійсності. Семантика базових онімів у повторюваних
>   ситуаціях видозмінюється, руйнуються вихідні культурні межі, виникає
>   ігрова модальність.

Comment: Поправив CAPS. Взагалі кажучи, є плаґіни для браузерів, які дозволяють зручно міняти регістр букв прямо у браузерному редакторі. Я користуюся [Case Changer/Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/case-changer/?src=search), але існують і альтернативи.